# No Interview confirmation via email. Should I still go?

Tags: interviewing

So I get a call from a company asking general questions about myself and in the end they tell me they want to see me in person. She asks me if so & so time & date is good for me. I say yes and she tells me she will send a confirmation email telling me whom to speak to at reception, time, date & location.

I know the location but I am in a dilemma if I should go or not? Moreover, I forgot the name of person who talked to me. So I call them & operator transfers me to someone and the call goes to voicemail. I haven't heard back after leaving voicemail.

Comment: Hello, I've marked this as a duplicate of the linked question; however, if your situation is different enough to where those answers don't help, please [edit] this one with more details, and make it clear what your question is in the post body. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Go to the interview.** Better to go to an interview that doesn't happen than to not turn up for an interview when you are expected. Even if it doesn't happen, they're like to feel bad and re-schedule you in for a later date.

You're fine just to turn up for the company and say you're there for the interview - that's usully enough for most companies except the really, really big.

The exception to this might be if you have to make an expensive commute - don't spend lots of money if you can't confirm the interview exists.

Dumb question, but did you check your spambox?

---

Anecdote here: When I started my last job, I asked a question about the start date & time, but never got an answer. I was only about 80% sure I actually had a job to turn up to. I turned up anyway and everything was fine, but the CEO at the time *had* noticed that they'd forgotten to confirm everything and apologised sincerely. Sometimes just hoping for the best works out fine.

Comment: I think I would go, also I did check my spambox. Let's see how that turns out. Though it's a long commute but I think I can manage. I called again and the call again went to a voicemail.

Comment: Moreover what should I ask when I am at reception since I don't really know whom to speak?

Comment: @user3777390 If you don't remember her name ask who normally handles HR. If the name sounds familiar then say oh yeah that must have been her.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the interview.

When you get there, introduce yourself to the receptionist with "Yes, my name is [x], I was scheduled for an interview today but they did not tell me who it would be with."

One of two things will happen. You will be on the schedule, and they will say "Oh, it's with [y]", and then when you get into the interview say "Thank you for seeing me [y]". Make no allusion to not getting the email unless it is brought up.

Alternatively, they will say "We don't have you on the schedule, let me call [z] and see what happened." Hopefully if that happens, it's [z] that said they would send the email and that's who they are contacting to find out.